# What is the difference between R.Net and Deedle library?

Tags: f#, deedle, r.net

I am working on a data analysis project and 
I have tried Deedle data library on my C# application 
I find that  Deedle is a useful library, it provides timeseries and dataframe for C# and F#. But my question is May i know what is the difference for this library and R.Net one?
If i wanna do some data analysis and statistical oriented project, 
shouldn't i use R.Net instead of Deedle library? 
Please advise. Thanks a lot

Comment: I found:  http://bluemountaincapital.github.io/Deedle/rinterop.html  ................... and ................. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-w7o9PHsnP8  From what I can tell, they aren't mutually exclusive. Apparently there are solutions entailing the use of both - yes in Deedle!

Comment: I thought if you want to use R, you need to install [Deeldle R plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Deedle.RPlugin), which has a dependency on R.Net

Answer (score 2):

Quick summary:

- Deedle is a data frame and (time) series library for F# and C# and it is written in F#, so it all runs on .NET.
- R.NET (and also RProvider) give you access to native R packages and you can access the native R data frame functions too

Basically, Deedle lets you do data analysis on .NET and when you need functions that are not available in Deedle (or some other advanced statistics), you can use R.NET and F# R type provider to call a native R package.